# Vala get icon from theme with spesific size?

Tags: image, gtk, vala

I want to get an icon from system and show it in `Gtk.Image` but in a spesific size.

[Gtk.Image](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Image.html).icon_size property is an enum, it isn't setting pixel width or height. ([Gtk.IconSize](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.IconSize.html))

This is how I get icon from system theme:

```cs
var icon = new Gtk.Image.from_icon_name("icon_name", 0);
...

// Something like `icon.set_size(150, 150);` ?
```

But even it is a .svg file in .icons folder, it is displaying as too small like 16x16.

I want to display it like 150x150.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I've solved:

```cs
// 150 is pixel size:
var icon_theme = IconTheme.get_default();
var pixbuf_icon = icon_theme.load_icon("icon-name", 150, IconLookupFlags.FORCE_SVG);

var final_img = new Image.from_pixbuf(pixbuf_icon);
// Use final_img...
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the (poorly named) pixel size

```
var icon = new Gtk.Image.from_icon_name("icon_name", DIALOG);
                            // Just use anthing here ^^^^^^^
icon.pixel_size = 150
```